# Meaning of rx_fcs_errors

Tags: linux-networking, ifconfig, ethtool

On my server I do see RX frame errors in ifconfig:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether d0:50:99:30:f6:81  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 11604295  bytes 3261247616 (3.0 GiB)
        RX errors 7339  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 7333
        TX packets 15597184  bytes 12823395455 (11.9 GiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 18
```

by digging deeper, I found the following error counter going up in ethtool -S eth0:

```
rx_fcs_errors: 7326
```

However, I was not able to find any meaninful explanation of what this counter means. I do not really have issues with my NIC, but with my openVPN connections to this small server, hence was trying to find a root-cause. Need to buy a new NIC?

Thanks